# ggplot does not show me the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I am trying to add a legend on the plot but it is not working. Here is my example dataset:

```
structure(list(hour = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                    "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
                    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), 
           average = c(2.61835748792271, 2.11352657004831, 
                       1.71497584541063, 1.40338164251208, 
                       1.15700483091787, 1.86376811594203, 
                       1.83574879227053, 1.83478260869565, 
                       1.1256038647343,  1.7512077294686, 
                       2.4951690821256, 2.08695652173913, 
                       3.52898550724638,3.85990338164251, 
                       3.96376811594203, 4.00968523002421, 
                       3.9225181598063, 3.96610169491525, 
                       3.89588377723971, 3.95883777239709, 
                       3.81884057971014, 3.71497584541063, 4.5, 
                       3.08454106280193), 
          avg_arrivals = c(2.71428571428571,  1.91666666666667, 
                           1.30612244897959, 1.38, 1.85106382978723, 
                           1.79583333333333, 1.14285714285714, 
                           2.93877551020408, 3.33333333333333, 
                           4.82456140350877, 6.03448275862069, 
                           6.47368421052632, 6.53448275862069, 
                           6.48275862068965, 5.77586206896552, 
                           6.49122807017544, 6.37931034482759, 
                           5.89655172413793, 5.70689655172414, 
                           6.17241379310345, 5.77586206896552, 
                           4.27586206896552, 4.1551724137931, 
                           2.7719298245614)), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Here is the R code for it and used ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(hour), y = percent_occ, 
                 group = hour)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha=0.7, width = 0.50, fill="bars" ) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percent_arrivals)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = percent_arrivals, group = 1, color = 
                  "line")) + # color = "line 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")
```

Comment: Your plot code doesn't run for me with your dataset (there are missing variables, like `percent_occ`).  Can you clarify what you want the legend to look like?  Your current code looks like you are making a legend for the line but not for any other layer.

Comment: Also, it is good to remove all aspects of the ggplot which do not actually relate to the problem. All the theme options, labels, and scales are redundant and only make it harder for people to see where the error comes in.

Comment: hello both, thank you for helping. Yes, @aosmith - I did incread the limits - from 7.5 to 50. Now you will probably see the bars. @ Mikey Harper - I did delete and minimize my code.

Comment: @GabrielBurcea thanks for your amendments, it looks much better!

Comment: What are "bars" and "lines" that you're referencing for the fill and color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have misnamed the data in the provided example, with `average` being `percent_occ` and `avg_arrivals` being `percent_arrivals`. Running your example code results in the error:

> Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'bars'

This comes from the following:

`geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha=0.7, width = 0.50, fill="bars")`

The problem is that ggplot is looking for the colour `bars`, which is not a valid colour name. If you instead want a colour to be assigned to the value based on a variable name, you need to specify it within the `aes()` argument.

Using this in your example:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(hour), y = percent_occ, group = hour)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha=0.7, width = 0.50, aes(fill="bars")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percent_arrivals)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = percent_arrivals, group = 1, color = "line"))
```

[image]

If you wish to define the colour of a variable which is mapped to an aesthetic using `aes()`, you will have to add a colour scale command to override the ggplot default pallete. For your example including these:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(hour), y = percent_occ, group = hour)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha=0.7, width = 0.50, aes(fill="bars")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percent_arrivals)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = percent_arrivals, group = 1, color = "line")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow4"))
```

Comment: thank you for helping. i wish somehow will keep the colour I have given: yellow4 for bars and black for lines. Is there a way I can keep them?And tried to place the legend bellow the plot but it doesn't do that

Comment: yes, that is right, I have done changes and that is why I have other variables.

Comment: Updated to explain how you set the colours. Please upvote and mark as accepted if you are happy with the answer :)